# Ember.js how to load an array of simple ember objects

Tags: ember.js

What is the best way of creating an array of ember objects from an array of json objects objects?

I can use SetProperties on each individual object like this:

```
var ret = Ember.A();

pojos.forEach(function(obj){
  var em = Ember.Object.create({});
  emCluster.setProperties(obj);
  ret.push(emCluster);
});
```

But is there a one line way of obtaining the same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd `map` instead of using `forEach`:

```
pojos.map(function(obj){
  return Ember.Object.create().setProperties(obj);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through objects?

Answer (score 1):

Yep:

```
var ret = pojos.map(function(data) { return Ember.Object.create(data); });
```

Comment: This doesn't have the same result. `create` has different meaning than `setProperties`.

Comment: True, but without full context, not sure it would make a big difference, as we don't know if those objects will later be bound or not. If so, the overhead cost would be paid at binding. But interesting to have this subtle difference underlined. Thks. :)

Comment: Actually, the major difference is that if you use setProperties  computed property setters will be called. With create, they'd be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my training-app to get json from remote server and parse it to array of objects.

```
App.Model.reopenClass({
  allItems: [],
  find: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://remote_address/models.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      context: this,
      success: function(data){
        data.forEach(function(model){
          this.allItems.addObject(App.Model.create(model)) <-------------------
        }, this)
      }
    })
    return this.allItems;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = (Em.Object.create pojo for pojo in pojos)
```